# PHP FTP + Passive FTP Server Behind NAT

Tags: php, ftp, passive

I tried reaching out on stackoverflow and they referred me here. If you don't mind I am just copy and pasting my original question here:

I'm trying to do an ftp upload between my website and a remote server.

I'm getting this error PHP Warning: ftp_put(): php_connect_nonb() failed: Operation now in progress (115).

I did research and I believe this is the problem http://www.elitehosts.com/blog/php-ftp-passive-ftp-server-behind-nat-nightmare/

The thing is, I cannot download the patch because I'm using Godaddy Cpanel, and they said the hosting we have does not allow it and I also cannot ssh into it to be able to run command line.

I read that in PHP v5.6+ the patch was applied but I cannot get ftp_set_option($ftpconn, USEPASVADDRESS, true); to work. It doesn't recognize USEPASVADDRESS, which I thought it would because I'm using v5.6.22.

Comment: I want to add that someone had said "It's not PHP bug, it's misconfigured FTP server. The newer versions of PHP can just workaround the problem. ". I had our IT guy set it up and he is unsure of what is going on so if anyone has ever experienced this please reach out

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38982901/850848

Answer (score 1):

Use `FTP_USEPASVADDRESS` instead of `USEPASVADDRESS`